# Date range with occurrence sum

Tags: pandas

I have a potentially big dataframe containing datetimes sourced from a date range query as such:

```
0   2022-11-20 00:02:22.630968+00:00
1   2022-11-23 00:03:02.134938+00:00
2   2022-11-23 00:03:50.589251+00:00
3   2022-11-26 00:05:17.568843+00:00
4   2022-11-26 00:05:22.653905+00:00
5   2022-11-26 00:05:22.653905+00:00
6   2022-11-26 00:05:22.653905+00:00
```

I need to reshape it into a list of date with number of date occurrences in the second row, no date occurrence must be zero filled as such:

```
2022-11-20 1
2022-11-21 0
2022-11-22 0
2022-11-23 2
2022-11-24 0
2022-11-25 0
2022-11-26 4
```

What is the most efficient way to achieve that with Pandas ?

If that's useful.. the end goal is to feed that data to [Calplot](https://calplot.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd

series = pd.Series([
    "2022-11-20T00:02:22.630968+00:00",
    "2022-11-23T00:03:02.134938+00:00",
    "2022-11-23T00:03:50.589251+00:00",
    "2022-11-26T00:05:17.568843+00:00",
    "2022-11-26T00:05:22.653905+00:00",
    "2022-11-26T00:05:22.653905+00:00",
    "2022-11-26T00:05:22.653905+00:00"
])

date_occurrences = pd.to_datetime(series).dt.date.value_counts()

# If your original series is sorted, you can just use the first and last value
start, end = date_occurrences.index.min(), date_occurrences.index.max()

all_dates = pd.date_range(start, end)

out = date_occurrences.reindex(all_dates, fill_value=0)
```

out is a `pd.Series` with the dates as index and counts as values:

```
2022-11-20    1
2022-11-21    0
2022-11-22    0
2022-11-23    2
2022-11-24    0
2022-11-25    0
2022-11-26    4
Freq: D, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`date_range`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.date_range.html) to build a range of dates from minimum value to maximum value of dates in your original dataframe and then use that to create a dataframe and then map the dates to a [`value_counts()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) series built from the original df.

Lets assume your original dataframe is `df` and column having dates is `date`, then you can do:

```
idx = pd.date_range(df["date"].dt.date.min(), df["date"].dt.date.max())
out = pd.DataFrame(data=idx, columns=["date"])
out["num_occurrences"] = (
    out["date"].map(df["date"].dt.date.value_counts()).fillna(0).astype(int)
)
print(out)

        date  num_occurrences
0 2022-11-20                1
1 2022-11-21                0
2 2022-11-22                0
3 2022-11-23                2
4 2022-11-24                0
5 2022-11-25                0
6 2022-11-26                4
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `df` is your dataframe and `Datetime` is the column name, here is a proposition with [`pandas.Series.reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.reindex.html) :

```
from calplot import calplot

ser = pd.to_datetime(df["Datetime"]).dt.date

(
    df
      .assign(Datetime= ser)
      .squeeze()
      .value_counts()
      .reindex(pd.date_range(ser.min(),
                             ser.max()), fill_value=0)
      .pipe(lambda x: calplot(x, cmap='YlGn', colorbar=False))
)
```

##### # Output :

[image]

*Intermediates :*

```
2022-11-20    1
2022-11-21    0
2022-11-22    0
2022-11-23    2
2022-11-24    0
2022-11-25    0
2022-11-26    4
Freq: D, Name: Datetime, dtype: int64 <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
```